Issue with Mapping PostgreSQL inet Field to C# IPAddress Property in ASP.NET Core Entity Framework
I'm encountering an issue with mapping PostgreSQL's inet field to C#'s IPAddress property in an ASP.NET Core Entity Framework application.
Here's the context:
I have a User class in my ASP.NET Core application, which corresponds to a table in a PostgreSQL database. The relevant properties of the User class include current_sign_in_ip and last_sign_in_ip, both defined as IPAddress.
public class User
{
    // Other properties...
    public IPAddress? current_sign_in_ip { get; set; }
    public IPAddress? last_sign_in_ip { get; set; }
}

I'm using Entity Framework Core with PostgreSQL. The DbContext is configured as follows:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }
}

And the PostgreSQL connection is set up like this:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PSQL"));
});

In my controller, I have an action to retrieve users:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> Getusers()
{
    var users = await _context.users.ToListAsync();
    return users;
}

However, upon executing return users;, I encounter the following error:
10045): The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.
   at System.Net.IPAddress.ThrowSocketOperationNotSupported()
   at System.Net.IPAddress.get_ScopeId()

I suspect that the issue lies in the mapping of the PostgreSQL inet field to the IPAddress properties in C#. How can I resolve this mapping issue and retrieve the IPAddress values correctly from the PostgreSQL database?
Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!
